# How to define individual legend elements in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to create sensible legends for this chart.

I am using R version 3.5.2 and ggplot2 version 3.1.0.9000.

What I have so far:

```
as.data.frame(list(
  name = c('alice', 'bob', 'charlie'),
  y = c(2, 3, 3.5),
  y_min = c(1, 1.5, 1.25),
  y_max = c(4, 3.5, 7),
  asterisk = c(6, 3.75, 9)
  )
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = 'main', shape = 'main'), size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(y = asterisk, color = 'asterisk', shape = 'asterisk'), size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = list('main' = 'black', 'asterisk' = 'red')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = list('main' = 16, 'asterisk' = 42)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = y_min, yend = y_max, xend = name)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I am hoping to get the legend to show just a large-black-dot and a small-red-asterisk, preferably under one header. There is no large-red-dot or small-black-asterisk, and it is confusing that those symbols appear in the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give both legends the same name so they become one

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y=y, x=name)) +
  geom_point(aes(color='main', 
                 shape='main'), size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(y=asterisk, 
                 color='asterisk', 
                 shape='asterisk'), size=6) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "legend_title", # changed name here
                     values=c('main'='black', 'asterisk'='red')) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "legend_title", # and here
                     values=c('main'=16, 'asterisk'=42)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y=y_min, yend=y_max, xend=name)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**data**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  name = c('alice', 'bob', 'charlie'),
  y = c(2, 3, 3.5),
  y_min = c(1, 1.5, 1.25),
  y_max = c(4, 3.5, 7),
  asterisk = c(6, 3.75, 9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```